# BulkWriteError in MongoDB in NodeJS Client

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, error-handling

I'm trying to insert a document every two seconds in a mongo database. After inserting the first document the client throws a **BulkWriteError**

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
var dbObject = db.db(DBName);

var insertJSONType = {latitude: getRandomArbitrary(30,50), longitude: getRandomArbitrary(30,50)}

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    dbObject.collection(collectionName).insert(insertJSONType, (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Document inserted successfully {nInserted: 1}")
        db.close()
    })
    sleep.sleep(2)
}
```

The error thrown is this.

```
node mongo.js
Document inserted successfully {nInserted: 1}

/home/user/random/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:132
         throw err;
         ^
BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: latlong.data index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5b237dcc4353c06c04a4cf38') }
at resultHandler (/home/gowtham/random/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:459:11)
at /home/gowtham/random/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:544:18
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

What am I supposed to be missing here? I did some searching on the internet but couldn't seem to be any good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbObject.collection(collectionName).insert
```

In this line, you are using `insert` method which inserts each doc with a unique ID in MongoDB. At the same time it errors out if it finds a duplicate ID (as your error shows).

Looks like you are trying to insert the same Object multiple times. Try using

```
myCollection.bulkWrite(records, { ordered: false });
```

where `records` can be

```
records.push(
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: _id},
            update: { $set: { insertJSONType } },
            upsert: true
        }
    }
);
```

This will try filtering if there already exists a doc with `_id`. If not, the `upsert: true`, will add a new doc. If a doc with `_id` already exists, then it updates that doc.